# How to find out the total number, based on particular conditions

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Let's say, I have a sheet with these 2 columns, where column A is for 'Remarks' and B is for 'Date'. 2nd and 4th rows are intentionally left blank to simulate that no Remarks and Date are provided.

```
A           B 
--------    -----------
Auto Closed 11/25/2018

DEC-2018    12/3/2018

Auto Closed 12/5/2018
Auto Closed 12/12/2018
```

Now, I need to find out the number of records that are "Auto Closed" in December (12).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A; "Auto Closed"; 
          B2:B; ">"&DATE(2018; 11; 30);
          B2:B; "<"&DATE(2019;  1;  1))
```


[image]

or:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A; "Auto Closed";
          B2:B; ">"&43434;
          B2:B; "<"&43466)
```


[image]